# Chromium does not start after update on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium

Updated Ubuntu this morning. I saw a message about chromium switching to snap.
Now chromium does not starts:

```
jedi@Kramer:~$ chromium
[24999:25138:0722/180759.356229:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(622)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.174" (uid=1000 pid=24999 comm="/snap/chromium/1229/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
[25139:25139:0100/000000.413388:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
[25139:25160:0100/000000.485651:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(272)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[25139:25160:0100/000000.485709:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(272)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[25139:25160:0100/000000.485736:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(272)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[last line repeated multiple times]
```

Same message with `chromium-browser`.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
$ snap info chromium
name:      chromium
summary:   Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
publisher: Canonical#
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/chromium
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all
  Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 18:07 CEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    84.0.4147.89 2020-07-15 (1229) 166MB -
  latest/candidate: 84.0.4147.89 2020-07-18 (1235) 166MB -
  latest/beta:      84.0.4147.85 2020-07-09 (1222) 164MB -
  latest/edge:      85.0.4183.26 2020-07-17 (1234) 166MB -
installed:          84.0.4147.89            (1229) 166MB -
WARNING: There is 1 new warning. See 'snap warnings'.
$ snap warnings
last-occurrence:  today at XX:XX XX
warning: |
  snap "chromium" has bad plugs or slots: system-packages-doc (unknown interface
  "system-packages-doc")
$ snap --version
snap    2.45.2
snapd   2.45.2
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-42-generic
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: This probably isn't related to the warning. I have exactly the same snap version, same chromium version, same warning about system-packages-doc and same Ubuntu version. But chromium starts for me.  I have snapd version 2.45.1+20.04.2 I suspect the apparmor configuration

Comment: But why would AppArmor fail now? Chromium used to work fine. It seems this is related to my system (which is in no way special) because I can't find any similar issue. There is also an error on sandbox_linux related to the GPU. I'll keep digging.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could figure out steps to reproduce it on a clean system, such as a VM. Also, I don't have chromium-browser binary on my working system. Please post output of `which chromium` and `which chromium-browser`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem, fixed it by moving to the snap edge release.

```
sudo snap refresh --edge chromium
```

Still has that same snap warning but at least chromium starts!

Comment: If this is all snap and sound, why is `sudo` required here, isn't that against whatever has been for snaps in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, until fixed or if you'd prefer to do it this way, you can easily install Chromium via 'normal' means.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

That should get you sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this looks more like a workaround. I would rather understand the real root cause and fix.

Comment: It is indeed a workaround. With a snap, you're largely forced to just wait until the next version is released and hope it's fixed. There's not much that you can do with them to resolve issues of this nature - AFAIK.

Comment: This snap is open source, so if OP solves the problem instead of working around it, I expect he can submit the fix upstream or failing that, fork the snap. https://code.launchpad.net/~chromium-team/chromium-browser/+git/snap-from-source

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the Snapcraft forum,

> The error is because the snap was updated to make use of an interface that has not yet been included in a stable release of snapd. This particular release of the Chromium snap on this particular version of snapd will always give that error.

There are possible two fixes for the same, as quoted on the forum

> To fix it, one of two things need to happen: (1) snapd 2.46 is released, or (2) a new chromium snap without the system-packages-doc plug is released.

For a more detailed information, please refer bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1887795).

A fix for the same has been provided. Please refer link in this [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1887795/comments/3) comment, but is still not available in the stable channel yet.

*Hope to get it soon!*

Comment: Reading the bug, I think the only consequence is the warning. It should not prevent chromium to start.